# More than one email content comes as blank page in php

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send approx 100 mail at a time using php. for this i am using the following code

```
 $this->view->dataSet['title'] = $title;
 $this->view->dataSet['message'] = $message; 


ob_start();
        $this->view->render('emailcontent', 'escalation-question-email-module-content', false);
        $emailContent= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$emailParam = new stdClass();
$emailParam->sendTo  = $email;
$emailParam->subject = $title;
$emailParam->content = $emailContent;
$this->sendMail($emailParam);
```

The above code is iterating approx 100 times through foreach loop.
I am facing a very odd problem the first mail only shows html content and other 99 mail content  appears as blank page.

I replaced ob_get_contents() function with file_get_contents() which is working perfectly but i have to use ob_get_contents() function.

Can you please identify what is wrong with code.

Comment: try to flush / clean your ob buffer                                   •ob_end_flush() - Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
•ob_end_clean() - Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

Answer (score 0):

Try bringing ob_start() right at the beginning of the script.